# Oxyhydrogen applied to a catalytic converter

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Recently people have been reporting that if you blow 'HHO' gas (Oxyhydrogen) into a used catalytic converter it gives off excessive heat.

Look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=hho+catalytic+converter) for any number of examples.

There is a [suggestion](http://www.e-catworld.com/2014/01/looking-at-the-h-cat-experiment-with-hho-gas-and-a-catalytic-converter/) that it is cold fusion.

What could this reaction actually be?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any current claim on "cold fusion" that could hold up against a scientific re-examination. Previous reports by Pons and Fleischmann now seem to be (mis)led by wishful thinking and dirt effects,  while those by Taleyarkhan were debunked as fraud.

As far as the inventions of Andrea Rossi are concerned, I'd be very careful with his claims. So far, he is apparently more "famous" for leaving behind stockpiled waste and huge tax debts.

The more recent findings of Rossi and Focardi and the related so-called ["independent study"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3913v3) were heavily criticized by [other researchers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6364).

In summary, all this nicely fits in the category of **pathological science**.

Comment: ...but what chemical reaction is happening here?

Comment: @DJA - one reaction I can imagine that will give of heat is simply the recombination of $\ce{O_2}$ and $\ce{H_2}$ into water. Combustion of hydrogen will provide quite some heat and a catalyst can easily make this occur at low temperatures

Comment: @Michiel Exactly! And if you don't want to "burn" it, run it through a fuel cell. But $\eta$ is not >> 1 here ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you expose a stoichiometric mixture (("Brown's gas," or any mixture between LEL and UEL) of hydrogen and oxygen to a catalyst, $BOOM!!!$.  A static electricity spark or even a cosmic ray can do it. The Hindenberg was not a pre-mixed flame.

Conservation of mass-energy (First Law of Thermodynamics) is enforced by Noether's theorems and the homogeneity of time.  If you want to diddle that conservation, you must break the symmetry or falsify mathematics.  Good luck on locally doing either for any fuel cycle.

http://physwiki.ucdavis.edu/Classical_Mechanics/Conservation_of_Mass_and_Energy/Noether's_Theorem_for_Energy 
(copy and paste the entire link) 
http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/noetherth.htm 
  The mathematics 
http://www.lhup.edu/~dsimanek/museum/unwork.htm 
 Perpetual motion machines